# Did the inventor present a working model for this patent

Tags: post-grant, history, us257885

In reference to the patent: [US 257,885](https://www.google.com/patents/US257885)

The patent has the word "Model" written at the top left corner of its first page. What does that indicate?

Here is a screenshot of the patent's PDF, accessed from Google Patents:

> [image: Screenshot of the patent]

Does it mean that the inventor presented a model before getting his patent approved?

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**, this means that a model was submitted or presented by the inventor. [Patent models were required in the US from 1790 to 1880](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patent_model), but the rules have since changed.

If no models was provided, then early patent drawings specifically state "(No Model.)"

For example, the next patent ([US257886](https://www.google.com/patents/US257886)) states ("No Model.)" indicating a model was not provided.

[image]

Based on checking out a number of patents, the practise of explicitly stating whether or not a model was presented on the drawings seems to have stopped around 1905.